# what is the type of PI, cos in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to ask about the type of PI and cos with Ruby.
What is the convention to write these types?

Can I write like: `Math::sin`, `Math::PI` or `Math.sin`, `Math.PI`?

Answer (score 11):

```
puts Math::PI
#=> 3.141592653589793
include Math
puts PI.class
#=> Float
require "bigdecimal/math"
include BigMath
puts PI(50).class
#=> BigDecimal
puts PI(50)
#=> 0.3141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592309049629352442819E1
```

Comment: Good to note that though Math::PI may be float, you can promote PI to BigDecimal, pointing out that 'type' is fungible (with strict rules) in Ruby.

Answer (score 11):

`PI` is a *constant* that belongs to the `Math` module. Constants are accessed through the `::` operator:

```
Math::PI
```

I believe it is called the *scope resolution* operator. It can also resolve to class methods, so you can definitely write:

```
Math::sin
```

The dot operator sends messages to objects, which is a fancy way of saying it calls methods. `PI` is a constant, so you can't access it that way. `Math.PI` is equivalent to `Math.send :PI`, which doesn't work since `Math` doesn't `respond_to? :PI`. Of course, you *can* fix that:

```
def Math.PI
  Math::PI
end

Math.PI
```

With `method_missing`, you can even make it work with *any* constant:

```
def Math.method_missing(method, *arguments, &block)
  Math.const_get method, *arguments, &block
end

Math.PI
Math.E
```

Answer (score 2):

First, there is no `Math.PI`, it's `Math::PI`--in this case, use the one that actually works.

```
[1] pry(main)> Math.PI
NoMethodError: undefined method `PI' for Math:Module
[2] pry(main)> Math::PI
=> 3.141592653589793
```

`sin` etc. are functions, and may be accessed either way. I use dot-notation, `Math.sin(foo)`, because it's easier on the eyes (matter of opinion), and similar to how other Rails code is canonically written (like Rails' ActiveRecord `findAll`, e.g., `User.findAll`), and how most other languages I use regularly do it.

*Edit* Oh, I may have misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right you are asking for the type of the value that cos returns. Rather then telling you what it is, I prefer to show you a way to check it for yourself.

```
irb(main):003:0>Math::cos(0.2).class
=> Float
irb(main):004:0> Math::PI.class
=> Float
```

Answer (score 0):

If you `include Math` in your code, then you can just write:

```
PI
cos(0.12)
```

You need to prefix `Math` only when `Math` is not included.

Have you tried using a gem wrapped around the Math module? Check out the math_calculator gem. That will allow you to write your expressions normally, eg. "4*pi*cos(0.12)" etc.